# Avoind re-indexing in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with this data from USA census that I imported to a dataframe and it looks like this:

[image]

I need to determine the state with more counties, i.e. I need to count the number of elements at the CTYNAME column which have the same STNAME. However, I am not being able to do this without re-indexing the dataframe (or creating a new dataframe) which I found inneficient. How can I improve my solution:

`census_df.set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME']).count(level=0)['SUMLEV'].argmax()`

Comment: How about `census_df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].size().nlargest(1)`?

Comment: @IanS This works great. However, I do not understand well what a groupby object is. Isn't this also creating an object with the same size of the dataframe, thus being inefficient? Also, I didn't know the nlargest function - extremely useful!

Comment: Here `groupby` will create a new object, but it only has as many rows as states, and one column. To be honest I don't think your solution was that bad, even though it's probably not the way most pandas users would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this would be the more natural way to do it, and is probably more efficient:

```
census_df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].size().nlargest(1)
```